# Extract Values of a Raster with several Bands at specific Points

Tags: extract, raster, arcmap

I need your help! :)

I am working with a raster layer that has 154 bands that present time steps of one month each. I want to extract the values of **all** time steps for specific points (I generated the points along a profile by applying the *editor function -> construct points* on my lines) but I only achieve to get the value of the first band for all points, and thus only the first time step. I used the *Spatial Analyst Tool -> Extract Values to Points*. Actually, what I really need is not only the first time step for all of my points, but all time steps for specific points. But I can't manage all bands of my raster showing up in my generated attribute table of the point shapefile.

I would be very grateful if you can help me. If you need more information just let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a coding site. For questions like this I would try https://gis.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Here is how you could do that with R

```
library(raster)
b <- brick('raster data file')
s <- shapefile('points shapefile')
e <- extract(b, s)
```